# How to get distinct entity fields using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

The model:

```
class User {String firstName, String lastName};
class Job {String name, List<User> users, List<User> checkers};
```

Disclaimer.
Job has name, users - that work at this job, and checkers - users that check the work results.

Here's the Spring Data repository:

```
interface JobDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Job>{
  List<Job> findByUsers(Collection<User> users); //this return list of Jobs.
  List<User> findCheckersByUsers(Collection<User> users); //I'd like to get list of users that check work for provided users. But it doesn't work this way.
}
```

Here's the plain SQL that I want to get:

```
SELECT DISTINCT checker FROM job WHERE job.user in (?1) -- ?1 - here are users provided
```

How to do this?

P. S.

1. I've read about [Projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections), but looks it's not the same that I want. I don't want to create any additional interfaces, as I already have the required.
2. Sure, I can use findByUsers method and then use Java stream API,     `jobs.stream().map(Job::getChecker).collect(toSet());` but it doesn't look pretty.

Comment: Doesn't `findDistinctCheckersByUsers` do the job? [From here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation).

Comment: @Tunaki, no, this method returns collection of `Job`, not `User` entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would put this method in UserRepository, since it's used to find users. But anyway, you just need

```
@Query("select distinct checker from Job job"
      + " join job.checkers checker"
      + " join job.users user"
      + " where user in :checkedUsers")
List<User> findCheckersOf(@Param("checkedUsers") Set<User> users)
```

Comment: but what's the job.checkers? I don't have such entity in Java. Sure, I have tables in database named job_users and job_checkers. How can I refer to the tables from @Query code?

Comment: In your question, you're saying that your Job entity has a `List<User> checkers`. If that's not true, then edit your question, and post your real code. Query expects a JPQL query. Not a SQL query. JPQL works on entities, their fields and association, not on tables and column names. If you have never heard of JPQL (or HQL), then read the documentation, because it's a crucial part of JPA.

Comment: oh, so job.checkers - it's a field of Job entity. Got it. Thank's, will try now

Comment: Great, it works! Futhermore, `join job.checkers checker` isn't required. Simply `SELECT job.checkers FROM ...` works.

Could you recommend me a useful complete manual for PJQL please?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql